# Why are some answers grayed out?

Tags: support, answers, user-interface

Sometimes I see an answer on SO that is grayed out. Is this done by the author or moderators? Why is it done? What is the difference in rationale between graying out an answer and deleting it?

Comment: @Stijn How did you find that question? I searched meta with almost the exact wording and nothing came up...

Comment: I used Google to search for it, you'll nearly always get better results than with the built-in search.

Answer (score 5):

It is done *automatically*, when an answer score (upvotes - downvotes) falls to -3 and below.

The idea is that the community has voted these to be *bad* answers, and therefore they are greyed out to de-emphasise them.

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that on Meta, the threshold is set at -8.