# Should I report dupe answers?

Tags: discussion, answers, flags

I have seen many times deleted answers by moderator with text *"Please do not post identical answers"*.

However, everytime I report an answer that is identical to the other, upvoted and older answers, my flag is rejected.

With *"identical"* I mean the solution to the problem that was already posted or a very similar provided code sample. I don't mean like copy-paste where every letter is the same.

> BTW, this is a very common scenario nowadays where the issue is already solved and even the correct answer is marked, but somehow a 0-rep or around 0-rep account pops out from nowhere and posts a zero-effort, very similar answer.

So should I just give up and let them die in a natural process or should I keep flagging it with a hope that the moderator actually cares one day.

Comment: *"I don't mean like copy-paste where every letter is the same."* ... then why do you reference a mod message where that was the subject matter?

Comment: I think you are confusing deleted with low-voted. As @scratte mentioned you need to be 10k+ to see actually deleted posts (which I see you're not). On the other hand, when an answer has -3 or lower score, it becomes dimmed (as you described). The message you are seeing is probably just a comment, might coincidentally be by a moderator... Maybe you should [edit] that to be more clear (or add a link for a specific example to clear the fog)

Comment: @Patrickkx I think you should define what you mean by "deleted" in your post. Is the post pink/rose or just gray? Are you seeing it with your current account on Stack Overflow? Does the user that posted the comment have a ♦ at the end of their username, like [these ones](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators)? Like others have noted, you may just be seeing something similar to [Why are some answers grayed out?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336410/why-are-some-answers-grayed-out)

Comment: Are you providing a link to the answer you believe is a duplicate?

Comment: Downvoting is a better option suggested in @Kenny Evit's answer. About the last phrase in your question about keep flagging or not, I guess the day we Joined SO, it is not only a moderator's duty but also our's to make this site work better and we reward/upvote the one who put on his efforts and flag/downvote to those copy paste answers of the people who seem to have put no effort. So its a part of our duty(that's what I think) to keep flagging these posts even if we catch moderator's attention or not but we should do if necessary.

Comment: Related topic: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385063/how-to-handle-cleanup-of-late-blatantly-duplicate-answers-surfing-on-popular

Comment: Devil's advocate: I think it's ok to flag answers on old questions that recycle solutions previously posted *while adding no new value on their own*. Raise a custom flag and link to the answer that already contains this information. Moderators usually oblige, as they should, because we don't want to fragment the same information across multiple posts or answers.

Answer (score 34):

First of all: you never raised any flags nor are you linking to anything, so you didn’t give us much context.

However, I’m pretty sure I have found the specific flag that prompted this question, which read:

> A duplicate answer. Spam.

If this was indeed the reason that promoted this question, then we can start  with the reasons why this flag was declined. You didn’t tell us what content it was duplicating but there is just one other answer to that question.

While the code looks a lot like the other answer, there is a difference between the two answers, so a direct comparison shows the answer is not just a duplicate. If you think the difference should be ignored, say, because the language of framework treats either variant as the same, please make that explicit in the flag as moderators are human and don’t know the ins and outs of every possible programming language and tool.

More importantly however is that the two answers were posted *within minutes of each other*. The second answer was almost certainly posted in good faith, and we generally don’t delete answers when they’re the same but posted in close proximity to one another.

So, for *answers to the same question that offer the same solution*, we only honour such flags if the newer answer was posted significantly later and doesn’t offer any improvement over the older answer. *Significantly* here means *hours* later, but most such answers were posted up to years later.

I’m ignoring the “Spam” part there. Stack Overflow uses a [very narrow and specific definition of “spam”](https://stackoverflow.com/help/spam-rude-and-abusive-flags), and the answer didn’t promote anything.

Your question is also alluding to having seen *deleted* answers with moderator comments on them asking the user not to duplicate answers. As the account that raised the above flag does have 10K+ reputation and so can see deleted posts I’m assuming they perhaps saw comments like the one I use:

> Please [don't post identical answers to multiple questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227). Post one good answer, then vote/flag to close the other questions as duplicates. If the question is not a duplicate, *tailor your answers to the question*.

I use this comment for a *completely different situation*, namely where a user copied their *own* answer from one question to another. Please don’t confuse these two scenarios. Moderators receive automated flags for the majority of such posts, but if you find identical answers by the same user, posted to multiple questions, feel free to flag those with a reference to the first such answer.

TLDR:

- Please do flag redundant late answers to questions that are already answered, where the late answer was posted significantly later than existing answers and where the late answer doesn’t add anything new. Do include a clear reference to the specific answer you feel makes the late answer redundant.
- If you see multiple copies of the same answer by the same user, posted to multiple questions, please let us know about those too, and reference the oldest answer in your flag. Make it clear the same user posted these.

Comment: My one declined flag did exactly what was described in the tl;dr: "This is a duplicate answer (adds nothing over the existing top-voted answer here: stackoverflow.com/a/912112). – Druckles Aug 14 '19 at 8:32". The answer has since been deleted anyway.

Comment: @Druckles: sorry, that was 18 months ago, I doubt the moderator that declined it at the time can remember now why it was rejected. The post was deleted by delete votes from regular community members *before* the moderator handled it, so it may have looked like you had flagged an already deleted post. I can't be sure however.

Comment: I wasn't looking for any kind of vindication, just suggesting I've had similar experiences as the OP.

Comment: @Druckles I’m sorry, but your situation was nothing like the one I am pretty sure the OP was referring to.

Answer (score 15):

> With "identical" I mean the solution to the problem that was already posted or a very similar provided code sample. I don't mean like copy-paste where every letter is the same.

I think this is the problem, and is what Tom was trying to point out in this comment:

> *"I don't mean like copy-paste where every letter is the same."* ... then why do you reference a mod message where that was the subject matter?

The mod message *does* mean "like copy-paste where every letter is the same".

It's fine for answers to involve the same solution or have similar code, *especially* if the answers were posted around the same time.

*If* a 'duplicate' answer is posted 'long' after an existing 'original' answer and there really are no significant changes, then downvote it and consider adding a comment to the duplicate pointing this out.

But it's almost entirely okay for someone to post a 'duplicate' that *does* have some significant changes, even if the solution is the same or it uses the exact same example code. In particular, the duplicate might better explain the solution or the example code.

Comment: Depending on the size and uniqueness of the "*exact same example code*", it might still be plagiarism and should be flagged.

Comment: Even in case of significant changes, posting the same solution/approach as an existing answer but with a way worse (or lacking) explanation is still worth a downvote.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In my opinion these "almost identical" answers are making unwanted noise. This is cool to see a lot of answers until you realize most of them are the same solutions as the main answer. Also I think theres a lot of users, "high-rep wannabes" who want to gain easily some rep by slightly modifying other answers. So from now on I will be just downvoting them. Cheers.

Comment: @Bergi Agreed – on both of your points!

Comment: @Patrickkx – downvote away! I sympathize with not wanting to see noisy mostly-same answers. I'm not really bothered by it anymore, if it's not actual plagiarism. There's some gems in some of them too though! Some answers are good precisely *because* they combine multiple answers or explain the same solution more clearly or precisely. It's also hard to discuss this concretely without a specific example.

Comment: @Patrickkx One thing to keep in mind, SO does not have a good mechanism for improving the quality of existing answers other than posting a new one. If somebody drops a nearly code only answer with no explanation, but the code is correct, what is somebody supposed to do if they want to add more information? You can't suggest an edit for that (deviates from author intent), you can leave a comment if you have at least 50 rep, but that's not really what comments are for, the only thing left is to post your own answer that uses a similar method to the existing one, but with improvements.

Comment: because ownership and author intent is considered important on SE, and it's valid for a content creator to reject an edit because "it's not what they want" the only choice we have is to either tolerate a certain amount of redundancy in content or give the first remotely correct rushed answer past the finish line (regardless of quality or mistakes) an unshakable monopoly until the end of time; IMO neither option is great but I'd rather err on the side of the first option than the second.

Comment: SE doesn't handle cases where the author posts a low quality answer and leaves very well, it's very hard to delete answers. Old answers get votes regardless of quality because they're the only post. IMO high rep users should use their immense edit powers to fix posts where the author is long gone, thinking only of what it would take to make high quality content hypothetically SE maybe should have just set up something to auto-convert posts to community wiki when the author no longer cares (e.g., if they haven't logged in for X amount of time), though that'd probably run afoul of licensing.

Answer (score 9):

Yes.

Occasionally I also find such answers and the approach I use is to Flag > In need of moderator intervention and then in it write something within the lines

> There's an answer which states the same - [LINK TO THE ANSWER]

This one happened yesterday: the flag was marked as helpful and answer was removed

[image]

---

The same process goes for users that write the same answer more than once in the same question (not as common)

[image]

or write the exact same answer in multiple questions

[image]

Notice the relevance in adding the links, the moderator said

> please provide exact links, we can't spare too much time on
> investigations.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes, like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64624490/how-do-i-make-remove-work-consistently/64624503#comment114266097_64624503) case, two answers are the same because they're the same obvious way to answer the question.

> @zixuan: This is the standard answer for this many times duplicated question. People will naturally produce the same answer, because it's the simple, obvious answer. – ShadowRanger 21 hours ago

Even though both are technically the same answer, as ShadowRanger noted, it is the *standard* answer for that type of question.

---

Other than in the case above, if two answers have almost exactly the same wording and also have the same code, then first downvote it and leave a comment.

---

If none of these cases apply nor are the cases mentioned in the rest of the answers then simply ignore it and move on.