# Rejected duplicate answer flags

Tags: discussion, duplicate-answers, flag-ban

When reviewing answers to [How to resize Image with SwiftUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56505692/8697793) I found some duplicate answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/63903363/8697793
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/60007870/8697793

which were identical to:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/56505725/8697793

---

And also:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/63899592/8697793

which was identical to:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/59928487/8697793

---

I flagged them as duplicate answers having in mind Martijn Pieters advice from [Should I report dupe answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/402550/8697793)

> Please do flag redundant late answers to questions that are already
> answered, where the late answer was posted significantly later than
> existing answers and where the late answer doesn’t add anything new.
> Do include a clear reference to the specific answer you feel makes the
> late answer redundant.

All these answers were posted much later and I included all the necessary information. But all of my flags were rejected and I received a 7-day ban. Why?

I flagged them as in need of moderator intervention (as they weren't spam, rude or NAA). The message was quite clear (at least to me):

> plagiarism, identical to: stackoverflow.com/a/56505725/8697793

Comment: Flag bans are automatic based on the success rate of your recent flags. What did you flag them as? (and if custom, what was the message? was it clear enough? did it point to the guidance on duplicate answers? did it link to the duplicate answer?)

Comment: Adding your exact flag message would be helpful - custom flags are tricky that way... What you think clear explanation may not be one (i.e. there was post recently on meta that said "this are *identical posts* but they are written very differently and don't look anywhere close to each other" - so for example if you use "identical to previous" or "duplicate of previous" when answers merely reiterate the same content it would be reason for decline)

Comment: I flagged them as *in need of moderator intervention* (as they weren't spam, rude or NaN). No such flags rejected recently. The message was quite clear (at least to me): *plagiarism, identical to: stackoverflow.com/a/59928487/8697793*

Comment: But they're _not_ identical, they're very similar sure but not identical, and I would argue not even close to being plagiarism, but instead just an unhelpful addition which just re-iterates what already exists in other answers

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is not plagiarism... and definitely not "identical"... I would put more text along the lines "similar, not bringing anything new"...

Comment: I don't see plagiarism there, just similar answers. OPs only has a few lines of code and the solution seems to be the addition of the `resizable()` method/function call. That answers like similar when the solution only requires a little code change is quite expected.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Between https://stackoverflow.com/a/63903363/8697793 and the accepted answer there might be a slightly different wording but it means the same and the example is also the same.

Comment: Yes, but your flag says "plagiarism" which isn't clear, plagiarism requires intent, and "identical" which it's not. It does _not_ mention things specifically in Martijn's guidance: *"redundant ... significantly later ... doesn't add anything new"*

Comment: *"the example is also the same"* ... they both have 2/3 of their answer borrowed from OPs code and then added the `resizable()`, it is obivous they both end up with similar results.

Comment: So does this mean that the flags were correct but I just used incorrect wording?

Comment: I would agree that this question needs a cleanup. It doesn't need 19 answers for such a small code fix.

Comment: Quite possibly, would be up to moderators to decide. You need to be quite explicit in the problems, if you mention plagiarism/identicality, then they should _definitely_ be plagiarised and _100% identical_. Otherwise you'll need to explicitly say why it should be deleted, if a mod sees a flag saying an answer is identical, when it isn't, I would expect them to reject it. But if it said "this answer was posted xx months after [linked] answer and adds no new material, even providing the same material and paraphrased text", I'd expect a higher chance of it being marked helpful

Comment: @Nick Good to know. I'll wait for a moderator to respond as well. I'm surprised as this wasn't the first flag I raised with this wording.

Comment: The mods are on a tight schedule, ideally you would provide _all_ the information you can, yes it's a bit annoying and yes it takes time, but it's the most helpful that you can be. (Remember that mods don't necessarily have domain knowledge, and it'll also depend on which mod it is that handles the flag)

Comment: Regarding the flag ban, you will potentially have to wait until that passes, it's applied when >25% of your flags in the last 7 days have been declined, so it might take a little time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't see these answers as either plagiarism or identical. So I see why mod decided to decline the flag. I would not be surprised if moderator deleted those anyway after they own investigation, but would not count on it.

Plagiarism is when post (or part of it) copied with no/little modifications from somewhere else, complete rewrite of the same idea is not one.

Identical may mean "same idea/concept", but without context it would be treated as "same word-by-word" which is not the case for those answers. Combined with "plagiarism" it pretty much guaranteed to be read as "exactly the same text".

In general flagging those posts was a good idea, but unfortunately explanation was not the most clear. Something along the lines "Late answers reiterating the existing answer - consider to delete. The `resize` answer was provided in ... and several late answers here essentially repeating the same".

Comment: Thanks, now I understand. I didn't realise that words I add in a flag may be taken so *strictly*. Looks like I just need to wait 7 days and flag these answers again, this time with a better wording.

Comment: @pawello2222 I declined these specifically because you claimed that the answers were *plagiarised*.  They were clearly not direct copies, and the answers were very simple, basic statements that multiple people easily could have arrived at independently. I didn’t look at them as late answers, your flag did not ask us to treat them as such. Sorry, we process hundreds of flags each day, in our spare time, so please try to be specific.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, I understand now why they were declined. Next time I'll be more *specific* and use words more carefully. And no need to apologise, I really appreciate your community effort.